# Automate Excel items to Word template

Tags: c#, excel, vba, vsto, excel-addins

Hi Stack overflow Gurus

I'm trying to help my work automate some of the things we do here.

**Scenario,**

We work with excel a lot (dealing with tons of number). When all calculations are done, we have a word document we need to copy some of the numbers/ other info to. This document is then shared.

**Hope,**

I want to create an Add-in in Excel such that once the calculations are done for any of the spreadsheets, anyone on the team should just be able to click a button in the toolbar to auto-create the final document. (I would like it to open the file browser, so we can pick from different templates)

**My basic knowledge,**

Using bookmarks in the word template seems to be the way to go for creating tags to eventually replace.

I want the add-in to be installed in Excel

I have been reading up on Office Web add-ins, VSTO, VBA and not entirely sure which to go with. What i have learned so far

- VBA seems to be at the document level, but i want this to be an add-in as it will apply to different external spreadsheets we will be getting. Not sure if my research is fully accurate though.
- I am thinking I will have to use VSTO or the new Web add-ins. I'm not entirely sure if the new Web add-ins are supposed to be updated versions of VSTOs or they have different use cases. Could anyone shed some light on this for me please
- Lastly, would VSTO or the new Web add-ins be able to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Sorry for the noob questions, I'm very new to all of this and I'm trying to teach myself all of this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick example which allows you to get data from a cell (Excel) in Word:

```
Dim o As Object
Dim pgh As Paragraph
dim temp as string

Set o = CreateObject("excel.application")
o.Workbooks.Open ("c:\temp\test.xlsx")
o.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add.Name = "x"
o.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("x").Activate
temp = o.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(3, 3)
o.Quit
```

Once the data is in Word it is fairly easy to put it where you want.  You an do it the opposite way by having Excel place the data in Word.

Comment: You will have to enable the Excel reference in in Word first.  Take a look at the following http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/integrate-excel-data-word-document/

Comment: Thank you. I will try this now :)

Comment: Can i please bug you for the C# counterpart to the code you shared above. I cant seem to figure out the CreateObject aspect of it.
Thanks

Comment: NVM Found it here for those that are also curious
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339282/how-can-i-open-a-word-document-by-using-createobject-in-c
and 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, VSTO is the right tool for adding custom functionality to an Office document – like reading a database into your workbooks and/or docking an interactive “Action Pane” beside your Word document.  But before you get too deep into the woods with VSTO, maybe all you need is VB, Visual Studio, and Aspose.Cells and maybe Aspose Words for .Net.  They have many well documented examples, the product can be downloaded and used before buying any license, and their sample code is a great way to get started with automating Office documents.  Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you. Off to go learn new things. If solutions already exists, then it never hurts to adopt them :)